# Limit # of records returned based on a form control

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to limit the number of records returned in a query based on the user input in a text box?  I know that I could use the Top Values if the number of records were constant, but this number will change.  I tried:

```
SELECT TOP[Forms![frm_GenerateMailout]![MailoutSize]]
```

..but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how, and where, you are using the SQL statement, but if you construct it as a string you need to concatenate it correctly:

```
"SELECT TOP " & Forms!frm_GenerateMailout!MailoutSize & ".. etc."
```

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there a way to limit the number of records returned in a query based on the user input in a text box?"*

Access SQL does not accept a parameter of any kind with `SELECT TOP`.

Unfortunately, when you try, the error message (#3141) does not identify the problem clearly:

*"The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."*

If you can build your `SELECT` with VBA, you can work around that easily enough by building the number into the string as Andy described.  Or you can use `Replace()` to substitute your `MailoutSize` value for a place-holder in a pre-built SQL statement.

So starting with ...

```vb
strTemplateSql = "SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT tblFoo.*" & vbCrLf & _
   "FROM tblFoo;"
```

You can do this ...

```vb
strSelect = Replace(strTemplateSql, "100 PERCENT", _
    Forms!frm_GenerateMailout!MailoutSize)
```

There are other possibilities, too.  If neither of our suggestions is appropriate in your situation, tell us about where and how you need to use the query.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know that I could only do it in VBA.  I did move it there and it is working.