# How to Update Top N rows in MS Access from C# using parameters for N?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select

I have this code working but I know I should use parameters instead.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lstViewFuentes.CheckedItems)
{
    cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE (SELECT TOP " + int.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text) + " seleccionada " +
                            "FROM PreguntasRespuestas " +
                            "WHERE nombreFuente = ?) AS pyr " +
                            "SET pyr.seleccionada='S'";         
     cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@nombreFuente", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.SubItems[0].Text ;
     cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

If you are agree with me, this next block of code is the way it should looks like, but this gives me an error

```
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE (SELECT TOP ? seleccionada " +
                        "FROM PreguntasRespuestas " +
                        "WHERE nombreFuente = ?) AS pyr " +
                        "SET pyr.seleccionada='S'";

foreach (ListViewItem item in lstViewFuentes.CheckedItems)
{

     cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@numPreguntas", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
     cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@nombreFuente", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.SubItems[0].Text ;
     cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

When I use the block above, I receive an error saying,  SELECT instruction includes a reserved word, miss an argument or is misspelled and so... I don´t understand why it doesn't take ? as parameter for N in SELECT TOP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access' db engine will not accept a parameter for `SELECT TOP`.  You must supply the value statically in the SQL statement.

See also [Limit # of records returned based on a form control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18434063/77335).

Comment: Ok, that's a limitation of Access' db engine, thanks, I feel fine now, I spent a lot of time trying to making this work.